# Apache Virtual Host Mix IP and domain names

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I have a case where there's a VPS running on Apache Server on main www folder, No vhosts. Now I need to host some vhosts but I need to access this specific web app from main IP address. The Other vhost will have their different domain name. To further explain my issue, here is a dummy example

I have a server with IP X and running app A without using vhost. Some apps uses IP X to access app A. Then Comes a need to add WebApp B and C with domain names `app-b.com` and `app-c.com`. Now I need to add the two apps without disturbing apps that accesses app A via IP X. The final solution will be to move the app A to vhost and update apps to access it via `app-a.com`, but that will take long time, so I need short term solution.

Any pointer or help is appreciated

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this? The [official examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) seem to cover your needs?

Comment: My problem is, Apache have one app accessed let say by typing `http://192.168.1.1`. Now I want that to be the case, yet add another app that is only accessible thru `http://app-b.com` and then another accessible thru `http://app-c.com`. That is `http://192.168.1.1` should access app A, `http://app-b.com` app B and `http://app-c.com` app C. Now I cannot get how to mix these even after reading the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having trouble with the official documentation, let's start from scratch:

First, open your existing site configuration for App A, typically at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.  Since you want to access App A with the IP address only, open the site configuration and edit it to look like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1>
    DocumentRoot "/www/app-a"
    ServerName 192.168.1.1
    ServerAlias 192.*
    ServerAlias *:*

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Next, create a new config in your sites-available folder, typically `/etc/apache2/sites-available` like so:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/app-b.com.conf
```

Next, open it:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/app-b.com.conf
```

What's inside should look a lot like what is in the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#purename). Edit it to look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/app-b"
    ServerName www.app-b.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, enable your site with:

```
sudo a2ensite app-b.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Repeat for App C.

In the future, to move App A to its own vhost, change

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1>
    DocumentRoot "/www/app-a"
    ServerName 192.168.1.1
    ServerAlias 192.*
    ServerAlias *:*

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/app-a"
    ServerName www.app-a.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: well written. Things are clear now. I can see where I was err-thinking

Comment: I was just implementing this and I found that `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1>` takes precedence over the others so that all requests goes to it (be it a `http://app-b.com` or `http://app-c.com`). If I disable that site, others works fine. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Apache loads configs in directory order, so rename the sites-enabled config file for the site A virtual host so that is the last in line.  That way, Apache will check for other matching virtual hosts and then fall back on the IP if no name matches.  It wasn't totally clear that this was necessary, but it should help now.

Comment: You mean in Apache main config or you mean I rename to z-app-a.conf so that is the last by alphabet? I din't get that very well

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo Second one.  Rename `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app-a.conf` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/z-app-a.conf`.  There shouldn't be any virtual host definitions written explicitly in your main apache configuration.

Comment: got it. Never knew that Apache loads configs alphabetically. How do you know all these things? I have searched wherever I could including Apache2 Docs. huh!

Comment: @StefanoMtangoo If you can't find answers to problems on Linux machines here or in the docs, check [Linux Questions Forum](https://www.linuxquestions.org).  There's a lot of detailed problems and solutions to learn from.